# Creating a multi-Language website - Static or Dynamic?

Tags: php, constants, multilingual

I am creating a website and it has to be multi-language. The translation has to be made and prefixed *(NO auto-translations api)*. My question is, what is more efficient?:

- Create one file set for each language.
- Create one file set and show text through PHP constants.
- I also thought of making a MySql query to get an array with all translations at the beginning of the document.

**Note**:* There will not be really large texts.

Answer (score 2):

Longer term, you're best option is going to be using one file set for each language.  If you use an industry standard format, such as GNU gettext, PHP has [built in support](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php).  Also, 3rd party translation companies and translation tools generally support the format, so long term site maintenance requires less dependencies on developers.

Comment: I am going to research about it. For example, how do you think a system like facebook is made? Single files?

Comment: I guess you can go to this question to explore more details for that 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18468018/php-menu-setting-for-language-settings/18468242#comment27145336_18468242

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [Zend Translate](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.translate.html) for a website I'm working on.

Most of the components in Zend Framework can be used as standalone components. I'm using the full stack but it shouldn't be a major problem to use only Zend Translate.

As for using a database to get translations, I think it depends on the type of content you are dealing with. For instance, for Joomla! there are components that store different versions of the same article, in different languages.

I would recommend Zend Translate, as you have different options to get the translations from: PHP arrays, INI files, gettext, xml.

You can event extend the adapter class to create a database backend adapter.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This could be an option, but I don't really need this kind of solutions because I am not dealing with large translations. The large contents are directly shown in their respective language (and won't be translated)

Comment: As I said, using Zend Translate as a standalone component should be any problem, just need to tell the adapter where your files are. These could be plain text INI files in the format:

TRANSLATION_MESSAGE_ID = "Hey, I'm about to be translated"

It actually can detect a folder structure.

Otherwise, you could implement a simple PHP array approach with a simple function.

Comment: Perfect. And, what is the difference between using a framework like Zend Translate and working with an own array? I mean, for simple purposes, isn't a Framework too complex?

Comment: Yeah, you could just include the desired PHP language file and return just the array containing your translations indexed by a message ID and write your `translate($message)` function to get the string from the array, shouldn't be more complex.

Comment: YOu can use this or other tools to translate it online but the integrity of the content is not guaranteed by referring the tools given by Google such as google trasnlate , ajax google  , and so on .

Answer (score -1):

I think it will help you: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v7vCp_TFcdU 
It uses `session` to store the chosen language and use an array for each language.

Comment: The question asks specifically what is more efficient. If the youtube video answers this, can you condense it into text here?